# How to call another jupyter notebook use REMOTE jupyter server use PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I created a Python project in PyCharm, new some jupyter notebooks, and then connect to a remote Jupyter server, it works good.

I see the notebooks stored in my local machine,

So when I want to use `%run ./another_notebook.ipynb`

or `import custom_python_file.py`,

`ModuleNotFoundError` occurred.

How can I call or import another file in this situation? Only upload the file to Server?